# Windows phone PhotoChooserTask Crop Image and get the original photo too

Tags: c#, windows-phone-8, windows-phone

In PhotoChooserTask you can specify the PixelWidth and PixelHeight properties so you can crop the photo.

What I want to do, is to get both of the original Image and the cropped one.
I don't want the user to pick the same photo two times !

is there anyway !?

thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Unfortunately no. Cropping image in code is quite easy, however if you want the user to crop it as they like, then you need to create custom cropping control.

To crop the image use Writable Bitmap EX library - http://writeablebitmapex.codeplex.com/